# How to check if each and every element has an ID?

Tags: selenium-webdriver

We just want to make sure that in the Web codes implemented by Dev team, every element has an `ID` property value.

How can I check?  Thanks!

Comment: which browser are you using for testing ?

Answer (score 2):

Test this xpath in your browser: `//*[string(@id)]` This will not only give you elements which have an id, but also whose id's have some value. It might be possible that the devs forgot to enter the id. Then, use this `//*` to get all the elements. If you want elements that have an id (blank or filled), then use this `//*[@id]`

Comment: Your solution is Simple and easy.  Thanks!

Comment: @Kevin - then please accept this answer. Try to use my code in a script which will automatically check things for you.

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming you're using Java) there is a method [`WebElement#getAttribute()`](https://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/java/org/openqa/selenium/WebElement.html#getAttribute-java.lang.String-) where you can get any attribute's value of the element..

> We just want to make sure that in the Web codes implemented by Dev team, every element has an ID property value. How can I check?

You need to find all elements first then inside loop you can determine whether every element has attribute `ID` or not using `getAttribute("id")` as below :-

```
public boolean isAllElementsHasId() 
{
    boolean isAllElementsHasId = true;

    List<WebElement> allPageElements = driver.findElements(By.cssSelector("*"));

    for(WebElement el : allPageElements)
    {
        if(el.getAttribute("id") == null)
        {
          isAllElementsHasId = false;
          break;
        }
    }
    return isAllElementsHasId
}
```

**Usage** :

```
if(isAllElementsHasId() == true)
{
    System.out.println("All elements in the page has an attribute ID");
}
```